# apache ignite grid failed to start, It was working well

Tags: grid, ignite

[Error on starting the apache grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVp07.png)
The apache grid working well, but suddenly failed to give the error.  This is the screenshot of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem with the classpath, it doesn't include `ignite-core` JAR file located in `libs` folder.

If `IGNITE_HOME` environment variable exists, make sure that it points to correct folder.